# I am trying to put 5 buttons in a code, but while hovering on them the hovered button keeps pushing the button to its left further left

Tags: html, css, button, padding

I am trying to put the below given 5 buttons in my code, but while trying to do so, the button hovered is pushing the buttons to its left, to more left. I guess this might be the problem with padding, but I tried many ways but none of them working.

```css
.buttons {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #003466;
  border: 0.8px solid #707070;
  padding: 6px 16px 6px 16px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.buttons:hover {
  border: 2px solid #707070;
  padding: 5px 14px 5px 14px;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding-left: 5rem; padding-top: 5rem;">
  <div>
    <p>Button Not Working Properly</p>
  </div>
  <button class="buttons" type="button">Edit</button>
  <button class="buttons" type="button">New</button>
  <button class="buttons" type="button">Preview</button>
  <button class="buttons" type="button">Export</button>
  <button class="buttons" type="button">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean? - *the button hovered is pushing the buttons to its left, to more left*

Comment: while hovering on a button, the button to its left is being pushed to 1 or 2 px left

Comment: It is because the change in border size

Comment: is there any way i can edit that coz that border size variation is mandatory

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by reducing the padding by same amount you are increasing the border on hover. Like This:

```
.button:hover {
  border: 2px solid #707070;
  padding: 4.8px 14.8px 4.8px 14.8px; /*Change This*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks AlamdarH, but i am trying to figure out without decreasing the padding in hover css. Is there any other way around ?

Comment: were you inspired by something? if yes, give a link to that so I can look at it and help you better.

Comment: Nothing like inspiration or something. Just thought so : lol

Answer (score 0):

Replace your css with this one.

```
.buttons {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #003466;
  border: 0.8px solid #707070;
  padding: 6px 16px 6px 16px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.buttons:hover {
  border: 2px solid #707070;
  padding: 4.8px 14.8px 4.8px 14.8px; /*Change This*/
}
```

After changing the css if dosn't work then ,You must need to open your file with chrome browser.

Comment: Thank you Mustan, I tried this way. But i am trying to figure it without decreasing the padding in hover. Is there any other way without decreasing the padding in hover ?

Comment: yes brother you can search on google outline border that's i think not decrese the padding